# Difficulty using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn making ajax calls using jQuery. But I am stuck at a very basic point in using jQuery itself. Follwing is the code I have,

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
      {
         alert("Hello World!!!!")
         $("#txt1").onkeydown(function(){
         alert("Event Fired")
         $("#add").load("newjsp.jsp?q="+this.value)

      })
    })
            </script>
</head>
<body>
<form> 
    Comment: <input type="text" id="txt1"></input>
</form>
 <p><p></p></p>       
<form id="add">
</form>
</body>
```

On entering any key in the textbox does not fire the event onkeydown(since there is no alert as "Event Fired"). I do not understand what could be the problem. Please help.

Thanks Rishabh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keydown` instead of `onkeydown`.

`.keydown( function(){...} )` is a shorthand for `.bind("keydown", function){ ... })`.

See also: http://docs.jquery.com

Comment: Agreed, however I would recommend to use `keyup()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob! Now I can concentrate on making ajax calls!!

Comment: @Rishabh Dont forget to accept this answer to show your gratitude and respect ;)

Comment: To elaborate Varavas statement: `keydown` fires when a key is pressed down (possibly more than once per keypress), *before* the default behaviour has occured (eg. input text in a textarea). `keyup` is fired when a key is released, which occurs at a less frequence rate (1x). When a key is released, the default behaviour has already occured.

Comment: @Kalle: Actually I did it at that moment itself when it was answered, but it did not allow since we have to wait for 11mins. So just forgot to do it. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Hey I have added another question to my original question, do you have any idea about it?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go right all the way, use `keypress` instead of `onkeydown` in a combination with a onetime binding to a `keyup` event

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("Hello World!!!!");
    $("#txt1").keypress(function () {
        $("#txt1").one('keyup', function () {
            alert("Event Fired");
            $("#add").load("newjsp.jsp?q=" + this.value);
        })
    })
});
```

Live sample in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bDjwr/),  (click *run* to start).

This **avoids keys like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>** being handled and also **avoids automatic repeating** of keys.

**note:** you should also filter out all characters that are not allowed in an URL. ;)

**keypress**
Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

**jQuery.one**  Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element. [link](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Hey I have added another question to my original question, do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Ask a new question please, not in this question ;)